# Query chaning in elasticseacrh

Tags: elasticsearch

I have one Index that is **projectRecords** in Elasticsearch.It contains some documents.Each document has one **docType** field,contains "Article", "Generation" like this.There is a relation between Article and Generation.My requirment is
1) I get all records match **org** field "user" value and **docType** type "Article" value.
2) Take first query output as input to second query based on this we can filter documents with date.
But i will do this with one query but i want in query chaining.
How can do this.
Thank in advance

Comment: Please provide the mapping and sample documents. Also can you please elaborate your use case. that will be quite easy for the contributors to answer you.

Comment: Elasticsearch is not a relational database. Seems like what you're trying to achieve is not what ES is really built for. I don't think you'll be able to do it within one query but you could use the results of the first query as a parameters for a second query.